# Setting the webroot to the pub/

Tags: magento2

I have a question and I'm not sure if anyone can help me.

I found out that I have to set webroot to the pub/ folder.

So what I did was basically change the document root for my domain in my cpanel - addon domains to /public_html/magento2/pub.

I know that it is pointing to the pub and my website works.

However when the email for product alert sends out the email. All the pictures are broken links. When I inspect the pictures on my browser, the link adds the /pub/media.....

However my domain should be pointing to the pub folder and should not add the pub again.

Can anyone let me know if it is normal and also the way I change the document root to /pub is the correct way?

I have a the managed cloud hosting with Siteground.

Thank you

Comment: Please try this way https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Answer (score 2):

What if you try adding the following to the end of your `app/etc/env.php`, then doing the usual cache flush and static content deploy:

```
'directories' => [
    'document_root_is_pub' => true,
]
```

I've had to add this flag to two clients of mine now in order to get `sitemap.xml` and `robots.txt` files to be generated in the `pub` folder. The clients are running the following versions of Magento:

- Client 1: Magento Commerce 2.2.4
- Client 2: Magento Commerce 2.3.2

I wonder if that might also affect the urls for content like emails generated from crons (Product Alerts, etc.).

### Cron/Cli Processes vs Web Requests

Processes that run via cron or cli are a little different than ones that happen as a result of web requests hitting the web server. They are not processed as web requests, so there isn't really a concept of DOCUMENT_ROOT and in turn no request hitting `pub/index.php`.

When the web server's document root is set to the pub folder, web requests WILL hit `pub/index.php` which is actually where the media path is configured differently to exclude `pub` from it:

**MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/index.php**

```
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = array_replace_recursive(
    $params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] ?? [],
    [
        DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
        DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
        DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
        DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
    ]
);
```

As opposed to serving from **MAGENTO_ROOT/index.php** where the default config below ends up being used that includes `pub` in the various paths:

**MAGENTO_ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryList.php**

```
public static function getDefaultConfig()
{
    $result = [
        self::ROOT => [parent::PATH => ''],
        self::APP => [parent::PATH => 'app'],
        self::CONFIG => [parent::PATH => 'app/etc'],
        self::LIB_INTERNAL => [parent::PATH => 'lib/internal'],
        self::VAR_DIR => [parent::PATH => 'var'],
        self::CACHE => [parent::PATH => 'var/cache'],
        self::LOG => [parent::PATH => 'var/log'],
        self::DI => [parent::PATH => 'generated/metadata'],
        self::GENERATION => [parent::PATH => Io::DEFAULT_DIRECTORY],
        self::SESSION => [parent::PATH => 'var/session'],
        self::MEDIA => [parent::PATH => 'pub/media', parent::URL_PATH => 'pub/media'],
        self::STATIC_VIEW => [parent::PATH => 'pub/static', parent::URL_PATH => 'pub/static'],
        self::PUB => [parent::PATH => 'pub', parent::URL_PATH => 'pub'],
        self::LIB_WEB => [parent::PATH => 'lib/web'],
        self::TMP => [parent::PATH => 'var/tmp'],
        self::UPLOAD => [parent::PATH => 'pub/media/upload', parent::URL_PATH => 'pub/media/upload'],
        self::TMP_MATERIALIZATION_DIR => [parent::PATH => 'var/view_preprocessed/pub/static'],
        self::TEMPLATE_MINIFICATION_DIR => [parent::PATH => 'var/view_preprocessed'],
        self::SETUP => [parent::PATH => 'setup/src'],
        self::COMPOSER_HOME => [parent::PATH => 'var/composer_home'],
        self::GENERATED => [parent::PATH => 'generated'],
        self::GENERATED_CODE => [parent::PATH => Io::DEFAULT_DIRECTORY],
        self::GENERATED_METADATA => [parent::PATH => 'generated/metadata'],
    ];
    return parent::getDefaultConfig() + $result;
}
```

## Update #1

After doing a little more digging, it does look like the CLI checks that `directories/document_root_is_pub` flag mentioned above to alter directory path configs based on the value. Since the cron technically runs from calling a cli command (`php bin/magento cron:run`), it does look like this might be affecting the urls:

**MAGENTO_ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php**

```
private function documentRootResolver(array $config = []): array
{
    $params = [];
    $deploymentConfig = $this->serviceManager->get(DeploymentConfig::class);
    if ((bool)$deploymentConfig->get(ConfigOptionsListConstants::CONFIG_PATH_DOCUMENT_ROOT_IS_PUB)) {
        $params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
            DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
            DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
            DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
            DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
        ];
    }

    return array_merge_recursive($config, $params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just set the docroot to pub following the Magento documentation but I also had to run

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and redeploy static content to get the files to serve from the correct path.